# NSTextField resigning first responder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to have my text field resign first responder when the user is done editing it, like when they hit enter. The delegate method is getting called but what I have now doesn't work, what is the proper way to go about doing this?

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
    [fieldEditor resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the docs on the -resignFirstResponder method:

> Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder:
>   method, not this method, to make an
>   object the first responder. Never
>   invoke this method directly.

This code should do it:

```
[myWindow makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

Comment: It's causing crash but I think it's another problem, when I do fix it I think your solution will work. Thank You.

Comment: The problem is definitely elsewhere. This is the proper way to cause *nothing* to be a window's first responder.

Comment: When I call this, it causes an infinite loop where the window asks the control control:textShouldEndEditing:, which calls makeFirstResponder: ad infinitum.

Comment: @SG1: Post your code into a new question. There is nowhere near enough information in your comment to even guess.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {

   [self.window makeFirstResponder:view];
}
```

where "view" is the parent NSView of your NSTextView control.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the NSControl delegate method:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notif
```

Implement this method in your `NSTextField` delegate (easily set in IB).

Then your request to change the responder, such as

```
[self.window selectNextKeyView:self]
```

should work.

Answer (score -4):

I am no expert in iPhone programming yet but the method you need to implement is "textFieldShouldReturn" implemented like this:

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear, Its not for an iPhone application. The method you showed is for UITextField delegate, which is for Cocoa Touch.

Comment: This not in osx sdk the every class begins with UI belongs to iOS not OSX