# How to resign focus on NSTextField when clicking outside

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I've a NSView with a editable `NSTextField` and multiple other subviews like NSView, NSSlider, NSImage etc.

1. After I've entered my text into the editable *NSTextField* and click on any of the other views, move the slider etc. I would like my NSTextField to lose focus. I've tried calling the `resignFirstResponder`, but that does not seems to work. How can I do this?
2. When I mark the text inside my *NSTextField* a blue background behind the text is shown. How can I change the color is this?

Comment: I think you should have asked these as 2 separate questions.  How are you going to accept an answer if one person gives the best answer to (1) and another person gives the best answer to (2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that you have a subclass of NSView called clickView1.h.  In reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431068/nstextfield-resigning-first-responder), you can achieve your goal in No. 1 as follows.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate];
    [appDelegate.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
}
```

As for No. 2, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks. Ad 2) had a typo. It is the blue marking background shown when marking the text in the *NSTextField* (for instance if you would like to copy it). Is it possible to change that color?

Comment: By saying the blue marking background, it sounds like you are referring to the focus ring.  I suggest you open a new topic instead of asking two separate questions under one topic.

Comment: Rather than looking for an app delegate, it would seem simpler to say `[[self window] makeFirstResponder: nil]`.

Comment: Its nice to know about the NSApp way of doing it. Imagine if you click in another window, then self is not correct. I use self.window most of the time.

Comment: self.window will return you the window, that view is bound to, not current window. So, self.window is correct, appDelegate.window is incorrect as it can be another window of your app.

Answer (score 3):

For question 1, I agree with BlueTomato that you need to make something else first responder, not call `resignFirstResponder`.  For question 2, subclass `NSTextFieldCell`, and in the subclass, have an override like this:

```
- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj
{
    [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes: textObj];

    if ([textObj isKindOfClass: [NSTextView class]])
    {
        NSTextView* textView = (NSTextView*) textObj;

        [textView setSelectedTextAttributes:
            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSColor redColor],
                NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
                nil] ];
    }

    return textObj;
}
```

Comment: That's another cool trick that he could use.  But isn't he talking about the color of the focus ring?

Comment: @BlueTomato, He said "behind the text", not "around the text", so I thought it was the highlight color.

Comment: I don't blame you.  I can use your code.  So you get my point.

Comment: Thank you, the *setUpFieldEditorAttributes* did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:

```
 [[NSApp mainWindow] performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder:)
                          withObject:yourTextfield
                          afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks for the idea. To give you a bit more context here is an elaborate answer of mine from a few years back https://stackoverflow.com/a/34335928/1041122